# Create a 7z .sfx file for different architecture with python

Tags: python, arm, compression, 7zip

I'm trying to create a compressed 7z sfx archive using python on a x86-64 Ubuntu 20.04 machine, and transfer it to a ARM EABI5 Linux machine, but I cannot find the appropriate functions or flags to use when compressing the object. I've tried using py7zr (https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr) and p7zip (http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) with no luck so far

Comment: What has the architecture to do with the compression?

Comment: @KlausD. forgot to add I'm trying to create a compressed .sfx file